# Set sprite rotation based on heading

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I want to set a 2D sprite's rotation so it faces the direction it's moving in. Currently I hooked the accelerometer to the sprite's linear velocity and when I tilt my device it doesn't rotate, only moves. I am running AndEngine on Android.

I want to calculate x+/x-/y+/y- to receive a value in rotation degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out eventually, to achieve this I did the following:

```
float radians=(float)Math.atan2(-acceleration.x, acceleration.y); //No Idea why I had to invert x axiz but it wouldn't work without it being done
float degrees=(float)Math.toDegrees(radians)+90; //Had to rotate my sprite by 90 degrees
radians=(float)Math.toRadians(degrees);
sprite.setTransform(sprite.getWorldCenter(), radians);
```

Answer (score 2):

[atan2(y,x)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) should do the trick.

So if angle=0 is in positive x direction,

```
angle = Math.atan2(y_velocity, x_velocity);
```

gives you the angle you have to rotate.

Comment: This was only part of the solution, after some trial and error I figured it out and posted the solution.